# NXOS roles for running tasks per host

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and trying to run different tasks on NXOS for different hosts.  I understood that we need to use roles but unable to follow the ansible guide.  Could anyone help:

```
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

     - name: L2-Commands
       hosts: N9K1
       nxos_command:
          commands:
                   - show interface eth1/1 brief                  

     - name: L2-Commands
       hosts: N9K2
       nxos_command:
          commands:
                   - show spanning-tree root
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 2 plays?

```
- name: Test1
  hosts: N9K1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - name: L2-Commands
       nxos_command:
          commands:
           - show interface eth1/1 brief                  

- name: Test2
  hosts: N9k2
  tasks:
     - name: L2-Commands
       nxos_command:
          commands:
            - show spanning-tree root
```

Comment: Thanks...It worked...Also would you be able to help is there a way to send the command along with output result to the file....    - name: save output to /etc/ansible/Outputs/
       when: ospf1.stdout is search('disabled')
       copy:
        content: "{{ (my_out.stdout_lines[0] + my_out.stdout_lines[1] + my_out.stdout_lines[2]) | join('\n') }}"
        dest: "/etc/ansible/Outputs/pre_check_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt".....As of now I am taking some nxos commands and getting only command output which is not clear to review which output is for which command...is it possible ?

Comment: that sounds like a different question